# Fourier Transform of a $N$-dimensional complex Gaussian

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-integration, gaussian-integral

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, given a complex function $f(x)\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$
f(x) = \exp \left( - \pi x^{T} (A + j B) x \right)
$$
where real matrices $A = A^{T}$ and $B = B^{T}$ are positive semi definite.

How to derive its Fourier transform in terms of $A$ and $B$? That is:
$$
F(\nu) = \int \!  f(x) \exp(-j 2\pi \nu \cdot x) \, \mathrm{d} x
$$

Comment: A potentially useful observation: note that
$$
f(x) \exp(-j 2\pi \nu \cdot x) = 
\exp \left( - \pi x^{T} (A + j B) x \right) \exp(-j 2\pi \nu^T x)
\\= \exp(-\pi \,x^TAx) \cdot \exp(-\pi j(x^TBx + 2 \nu^Tx)).
$$
Now, suppose that there exists a vector $\mu$ with $\nu = B\mu $.  It follows that
$$
x^TBx + 2 \nu^Tx = x^TBx + \nu^Tx + x^T\nu = 
x^TBx + \mu^T B x + x^TB \mu = \\
(x + \mu)^T B (x + \mu) - \mu^T B \mu
$$
so that
$$
f(x) \exp(-j 2\pi \nu \cdot x) = 
\frac{\exp(-\pi \,x^TAx) \cdot \exp(-\pi j((x + \mu)^T B (x + \mu)))}{\exp(-j\pi\,\mu^T B \mu)}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for the insights. Then the question is how to integrate $\exp(-\pi \,x^TAx) \cdot \exp(-\pi j((x + \mu)^T B (x + \mu)))$ over $x$. My blunt, and have no clues on how to proceed...

Comment: $A$ and $B$ don't necessarily commute, right?

Comment: @amsmath No they don’t have to.

Comment: So you require $x$ to be in $\mathbb R^N$ rather than $\mathbb C^N \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You usually take the Fourier transform only of functions defined on $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: One way I've seen the complex normal (or complex Gaussian) defined involves a Hermitian matrix $V\in\mathbb C^{N\times N},$ i.e. a matrix equal to its own conjugate transpose, that is nonnegative-definite in the sense that for every $z \in \mathbb C^{N\times 1}$ you have $z'Vz\ge0,$ where $z'$ is the conjugate transpose of $z.$ Then $z\mapsto \exp\left( -\frac 1 2 z'V^{-1} z \right)$ is a Gaussian function, where the factor $-1/2$ is there in order to assure that if you make this a probability density by multiplying it by a suitable constant, then the variance will be$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$precisely the matrix $V$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I understand your words. This question is different from the usual case: its background is an optical wave with amplitude curvature $A$ and phase curvature $B$, hence the non-Hermitian.

Comment: ok, I just noticed that I should have said "positive-definite", since I wrote of an inverse matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = U^TDU$ with a diagonal matrix $D$ and an orthogonal matrix $U$. Then
$$
x^TBx + 2\nu^Tx = \sum_{k=1}^Nd_k(y_k+r_k)^2 - \sum_{k=1}^Nw_kr_k,
$$
where $y = Ux$, $w = U\nu$, and $r = D^{-1}w$. Now, set $z = y+r$. Then
$$
x^TBx + 2\nu^Tx = z^T Dz - w^Tr = |D^{1/2}z|^2 - w^Tr.
$$
As another change of variable, set $t = D^{1/2}z$. Then $x^TBx + 2\nu^Tx = |t|^2 - c$, where $c = w^Tr = |D^{-1/2}w|^2$. We get (I'm not sure whether it's $1/2$ or $-1/2$ in the exponent -- you should check it)
$$
\int f(x)e^{-2\pi i\nu^Tx}\,dx = e^{\pi ic}(\det D)^{\pm 1/2}\cdot\int e^{-\pi(D^{-1/2}t-r)^TUAU^T(D^{-1/2}t-r)}\cdot e^{-\pi i|t|^2}\,dt.
$$
Now, setting $A_1 := D^{-1/2}UAU^TD^{-1/2}$ and $\rho := D^{1/2}r$,
\begin{align}
(D^{-1/2}t-r)^TUAU^T(D^{-1/2}t-r)
&= (t-\rho)^TA_1(t-\rho)\\
&= t^TA_1t - 2\rho^TA_1t + \rho^TA_1\rho.
\end{align}
We have $A_1 = V^TEV$ with a diagonal matrix $E = diag(e_k)$ and an orthogonal matrix $V$ and we get
$$
t^TA_1t - 2\rho^TA_1t + \rho^TA_1\rho = \sum_{k=1}^Ne_k(x_k-\tau_k)^2,
$$
where $x = Vt$ and $\tau = V\rho$. Since $|t| = |x|$ (which is the main trick here), we obtain
$$
\int f(x)e^{-2\pi i\nu^Tx}\,dx = C\cdot\int e^{-\pi\sum e_k(x_k-\tau_k)^2}\cdot e^{-\pi i|x|^2}\,dx = C\prod_{k=1}^N\int e^{-\pi(e_k(s-\tau_k)^2+is^2)}\,ds.
$$

Comment: You should assume $B=0$, $A= M^\top M$ and $\nu$ is purely imaginary, then extend to $A,\nu$ complex  by analytic continuation

Comment: Is it possible to further proceed with the integral $\int e^{-\pi (e_k^2 s^2+i s^2)}\,ds$?

Comment: Mathematica says that (for $c>0$, which is satisfied here)$$\int e^{-\pi(c(s-\tau)^2+is^2)}\,ds = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c+i}}\cdot\exp\big(-\frac{ic\tau^2\pi}{c+i}\big).$$